# No rings of video calls of whatever messanger

Tags: internet, video-calling

Mobile internet is on. I call to my android phone from some messenger on PC. There are no any reaction on the phone. Some time later I see a notification on the phone, that there was a call. I tried skype, hangouts, Mail agent, tango etc. All the same.

Standard calls works fine. 
Sometimes, when application is active on the screen of my phone, I see the call. When screen is blocked - the call has never been see. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any kind of "task killer" or "battery saver" apps? What phone is it, and what Android version are you on?

Comment: xperia m, android 4.3 official - 15.4.A.1.9, no taskkillers, but the mode of energy save and stamina is turned on.

Comment: Now, I turned these modes off and have the same effect.